# Is it appropriate for a Builder to modify a given value?

Tags: design-patterns

Wrestling with my conscience on this one.

I have a complex object Foo.  Foo has EnrichedBar.  In order to simplify construction of Foo, I am introducing FooBuilder.

Currently, it is incumbent on the client that constructs Foo to perform the mapping from Bar to EnrichedBar.

Is it appropriate to hide this enrichment within the Builder, or is that assigning too much responsibility to the Builder?

Comment: This question seems subjective.

Comment: Most design questions are, to some degree.  The code can be functional with either the client handling the enrichment, the builder handling the enirchment, or the client passing the enrichment off to a third class, and then passing the enriched thing to the builder.

However, they all have trade offs; the first increases the complexity of the client, the second increases the complexity of the builder, the third increases the number of dependencies the client has.

This feels like a sufficiently common scenario that I thought I'd poll the room and see if anyone knew a common answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's appropriate to hide it somewhere.

While, I'm not sure if it's the responsibility of a builder, factory or mapper, I'm fairly sure that it's not the responsibility of the client constructing Foo.

If we reduce it down, I suppose we can say:

- Something must be able to create a `Foo` (`FooBuilder/Factory`?);
- Something must be able to map a `Bar` to an `EnrichedBar` (`BarMapper`?);

So why not start with a `FooBuilder` that depends on  a `BarMapper` that has a method `Build(Foo theFoo)` that will use the mapper to create the `Foo` with an `EnrichedBar` using the passed-in `Bar` via the mapper. Your client can then depend on the `FooBuilder` to do the work.

While this might not be the end result, it's a working draft that's reasonably SOLID and might serve to salve you conscience a little.

Comment: Extracting the enricher as a service which the Builder then has a dependency seems like the best approach at the moment; that, at least, provides an easy way to move the enrichment logic if it's deemed to be better somewhere else later.

Just makes my teeth itch a bit for a builder have a dependency like that.  ><

Comment: I know that uneasy feeling: you know there's a better design out there but it just won't drop out.